# Is there a way to rename tibble without introducing backticks?

Tags: r, paste

Renaming columns introduces backticks, though paste result does not have spaces.

```r
tmp <- tibble(a = 1:10, b = 10:1)
tmp %>% 
  rename_at( vars( a, b ), ~ paste( 'id', ., sep = '-' ) )
```

Paste result:

```r
paste( 'id', 'a', sep = '-' )
```

Later, selecting and filtering becomes difficult with dplyr. How can this procedure be edited to either remove, or never introduce, the backticks in column names?

Comment: ... use a different seperator, e.g "_". With "-" you have to use backticks.

Comment: Standard names in R can only contain letters, numbers, `.` and `_`. Your names contain `-` (which usually means subtraction), so it is a non-standard name and you'll need to use backticks with it.

Comment: Right, I see. Thanks!

Comment: You can see `?make.names` for a bit of documentation about standard names. *"A syntactically valid name consists of letters, numbers and the dot or underline characters and starts with a letter or the dot not followed by a number. Names such as ".2way" are not valid, and neither are the reserved words."*